# Python ElementTree insertBefore command

Tags: python, elementtree

I would like to insert `permission`s in *Android manifest* files using **Python** and **ElementTree**.

On *Android Manifest* `permission`s need to be before `application` node so I would like to use an `insertBefore()` function like in *minidom*. Look like it don't exist at all on **ElementTree**, does anyone already faced that kind of problem ?
BTW I can't use *minidom*.

It's been 2 hours I'm looking at google search but can't find any interresting answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only requirement is that `permission` be before `application`, you can ensure that by inserting `permissions` at position 0 of the containing `Element` (using the [insert](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.insert) method).

```
import StringIO
from xml.etree import ElementTree

xml_str = "<root><something></something><application></application></root>"
permission_str = "<permission></permission>"

tree = ElementTree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(xml_str))
perm_element = ElementTree.fromstring(permission_str)

# insert our permission element as the first child
tree.getroot().insert(0, perm_element)

print ElementTree.tostring(tree.getroot())
```

yields:

```
<root><permission /><something /><application /></root>
```

**EDIT**:

You have a couple of options if you need finer grained control. Probably the best option is to install and use `lxml`, which does have an `insertBefore` capability.

If you prefer to stick to `xml.etree`, here's a more precise method of inserting new elements:

```
import StringIO
from xml.etree import ElementTree


def get_index(root, element):
    for idx, child in enumerate(root):
        if element == child:
            return idx
    else:
        raise ValueError("No '%s' tag found in '%s' children" %
                         (element.tag, root.tag))

xml_str = """<root><something></something><application></application></root>"""
tree = ElementTree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(xml_str))

# print our tree pre-insertion
print ElementTree.tostring(tree.getroot())

permission_str = "<permission></permission>"
perm_element = ElementTree.fromstring(permission_str)
app_element = tree.getroot().find('./application')
app_index = get_index(tree.getroot(), app_element)
tree.getroot().insert(app_index, perm_element)

# print our tree post-insertion
print ElementTree.tostring(tree.getroot())
```

which, when run, prints:

```
<root><something /><application /></root>
<root><something /><permission /><application /></root>
```

This has limitations - if there are several identical elements, it will insert the new element before the first one it finds (so if you had two application children of root with identical attributes and wanted to place a new tag after the first one but before the second one, you'd be out of luck). That said, I believe it accomplishes what you need it to.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But I will have other node to add, and not necessarly at the beginning, that's why I reall need an `insertBefore()` workaround.